# Vue Testing Library, Child Component receives props

Tags: vue.js, testing-library, vue-testing-library

I'm trying to implement some Testing Library tests on a Vuejs app, but I can't figure out how to pass props to a component within the test.

For example, I want a unit test for a component that appears inside of its ParentComponent template like this. I am trying to write a unit test for the ChildComponent.

```
<ChildComponent hereIsAProp="important info" />
```

I'm surprised this scenario isn't covered in the Vue Testing Library [basic examples](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/examples). Makes me think I'm missing some best practice around using/testing Vuejs props.

I imagine something like `render(ChildComponent, { props: { hereIsAProp: "new info"})` should do the trick. But I can't find this in the docs and whatnot.

Comment: "I want a test scenario where ChildComponent renders some default props" - this should be tested in child test, not parent, and not specifically default prop. It doesn't matter if there's default prop value or not, as long as empty prop is handled correctly.

Comment: @EstusFlask Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am trying to write a test for the ChildComponent. Are you saying there's no need to test the conditional logic in the child component?

Comment: You need to test with and without prop and assert the thing that this prop affects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing Libary's [`render()` is a wrapper](https://github.com/testing-library/vue-testing-library/blob/a620424be19e3158b89b575b7603aa7ab5d9f9ec/src/render.js#L54) for Vue Test Util's [`mount()`](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount).

The second argument to `render()` is passed onto `mount()` as mounting options, and `mount()` can set the component's props with the [`props` option](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#props) (in version 2x) or [`propsData`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html#propsdata) (in version 1x).

So your guess is actually correct:

```js
render(ChildComponent, { props: { hereIsAProp: "new info" } })
```